# Jest is not showing green progress bar during tests

Tags: jestjs, end-to-end, babel-jest

When I run my jest tests, the green progress bar and stats aren't printed to the console.

It just prints `RUNS path/to/my/test` and then at the very end after my entire test suite is finished, it prints the stats.

Is there any reason why the green status bar wouldn't show up?